# Selecting elements by bgcolor Attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select a bunch of td in a table whose CSS contains a particular background color (bgcolor attribute). How do I achieve this?

I have tried `$("[bgcolor=#FF0000]")` but I got error. `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': '[bgcolor=#FF0000]' is not a valid selector.`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF0000">January</td>
    <td bgcolor="#00FF00">$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes needed for selectors when you want find element by attribute value.

```js
$('[bgcolor="#FF0000"]').each(function(e){
 $(this).text('wow my bg is red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF0000">January</td>
    <td bgcolor="#00FF00">$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```